# Can not bind a model to $scope

Tags: angularjs

This is my HTML:

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group" data-ng-switch="name">
        <div data-ng-switch-when="null">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="name" id="name" data-ng-model="vendor.name" >
        </div>
        <div data-ng-switch-default>
            <label>Name: </label>
            <label>{{vendor.name}}</label>
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" data-ng-model="vendor.name" >
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Description</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="description" id="description" data-ng-model="vendor.description" >
    </div>
    <br>
    <div data-ng-switch="name">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" data-ng-switch-when="null" data-ng-click="save()">Save</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" data-ng-switch-default data-ng-click="update()">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

and this is part of my controller:

```
$scope.save = function() {
    // vendor.name does not exist in here, why?
    Vendor.get($scope.vendor.name).
    success(function(response) {}).error(function() {
        var postData = {
            'name': $scope.vendor.name,
            'description': $scope.vendor.description
        };
        Vendor.update(postData);
    });
};
```

I checked that save() is being called. Why *vendor.description* does exist but *vendor.name* does not exist before calling Vendor.get function?

Comment: Please provide a full Plunker example. I was not able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Problem solved, I used two HTML files, one for adding and one for editing. I think the ng-switch or ng-show were causing a misbehavior. Thanks anyway :)